# How to achieve this rounded gradient edges?

Tags: flutter

I want to achieve the following gradient effect in flutter where the gradient has rounded edges at bottom left and right.

[image]

```
Widget _buildTopBar() {
    return Container(
      height: .35.sh,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              const Color(0xFF1ED760).withAlpha(25),
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
            ],
            stops: const [
              0.0,
              .3,
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            tileMode: TileMode.repeated),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I also tried giving the container border radius. But it's not giving the desired effect.

Comment: That would not work on normal linear even radial, Better to create painter on that

Comment: Maybe this could work https://pub.dev/packages/glowy_borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Archit Arora Please review the provided code; it should assist you in achieving your desired output.

```
 Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Colors.black,
        gradient: RadialGradient(
         radius: 1,
              colors: [
                const Color(0xFF1ED760).withAlpha(25),
                const Color(0xFF1ED760).withAlpha(100),
                Colors.green,
                Colors.black
              ],
          center: Alignment(0, -1.9),
            ),
      ),
    ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with one of the following in your **BoxDecoration**, adjusting the radius or elliptical values:

```
borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50), bottomRight: Radius.circular(50))

borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(150, 40), bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(150, 40))
```

With the .elliptical option for instance, I got this:

[image]